# Code Igniter Ajax post show 404

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i´m doing a validation with AJAX and PHP, i want to do something like when you log in to gmail , you write your email and then the program validates if that email exists in the records, if succesful then it shows the username and email, else the program has to say: that email don´t exists, i´m using Code Igniter framework, the error in my code is this when i click the button to post email data:

parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0(…)

here is the code :

**Controller**

```
/**
 * Controller for email_validation 
 * 
 * @param the_user_email string
 * @return bool
 */
**dssad**
public function email_validation()
{
    if( $this->input->is_ajax_request() )
    {

    $the_user_email = $this->input->post('login_string');

    echo $the_user_email;

        $email_exists = $this->email_validation($the_user_email);

        if ($email_exists != FALSE) {

            echo json_encode([
                'status'   => 1,    
                'username' => $if_email_exists['username'],
                'email'    => $if_email_exists['email']
            ]);

        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode([
                'status'   => 0,    
            ]);
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        show_404();
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
 /**
 * Select a user email to validate
 *
 * @param  string  the user email to check
 * @return email if True
 * @return bool if False
 */
public function email_validation($the_user_email)
{
    $query = $this->db->select('username,email')
        ->from(config_item('user_table'))
        ->where('email', $the_user_email)
        ->limit(1)
        ->get();

    if( $query->num_rows() == 1 )
        return $query->row();

    return FALSE;
}
```

**View**

```
     <center>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="row" id="login-card">
                    <div id="card-slide">
                        <div class="username-div">
                            <div id="user-img">
                                <img class="img-circle" src="img\lorem.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="login_string" id="login_string" placeholder="               Enter your email">
                                <div class="form-group"> </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="btn-primary form-control" id="next-btn">Next</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pass-div">

                        <i id="arrow-left" class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                            <div id="user-img">
                                <img class="img-circle" src="" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <h1 id="Username_label">User Name</h1>
                            <label for="Username_label" id="Email_label">LoremIpsum@lorem.com</label>
                            <br><br>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" tabindex="-1" name="login_pass" placeholder="             Enter your password"  

                                 autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly" onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" />

                                <div class="form-group"> </div>
                            </div>                              

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" tabindex="-1" name="submit" id="submit_button">Sing In</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <p style="margin: 2em;">                        <!-- Forgot account -->
                    <a href="http://192.168.0.102/octopus/login/recover">
                        Can't access your account?
                    </a>
                </p>

            </div>
            </div>
        </center>
```

**Ajax Post**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#next-btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        url: '/octopus/login/email_validation',
        data: {
            'login_string': $('#login_string').val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){

            console.log(response);
            if(response.status == 1){
                $('#Username_label').replaceWith(response.username);
                $('#Email_label').replaceWith(response.email);
                $('#card-slide').addClass('show');
                $('#login-card').css('height','435px');
            }else if(response.status == 0){
                alert('This email does not exists.');
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);        
        }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that either your Controller or model contains syntax error or Somewhere in the controller or model you are echo/printing some data which you are unable to handle in the ajax response.

**Error Check**

1]  First check for unnecessary echo/prints.

2]  Try with simple controller code by removing model connection.

3]  If solved, then something is wrong with your model, if not then error is in your controller.

4] Always, get detailed response of your AJAX call by checking
Inspect Element > Network > XHR.
If your file contains error, the filename will be shown in red color in the XHR panel. (In Google Chrome)

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Happens most of the times with these MVC frameworks :D

Answer (score 1):

I see two potential problems. The first is this line in the controller.

```
echo $the_user_email;
```

This becomes the first piece of your response. It's not json and is probably the culprit.

The second problem

```
    $email_exists = $this->email_validation($the_user_email);

    if ($email_exists != FALSE) {
        echo json_encode([
            'status'   => 1,    
            'username' => $if_email_exists['username'],
            'email'    => $if_email_exists['email']
```

The model returns a value to `$email_exists` but you use `$if_email_exists` to set the array that gets encoded to your json response. Maybe I've missed something but I don't see `$if_email_exists` defined anywhere.

Comment: I saw that too , $if_email_exists[''] is the variable: $email_exists, my error, i´m starting with AJAX and Code Igniter, is the datatype i´m using right?

Comment: Yes, `datatype` seems to be right. That option tells JQuery what to expect back from the server. Except for the call to `echo $the_user_email;` you are returning json. I assume that statement was for debugging - right?